# Get text of comment in excel using vba with python

Tags: python, excel, comments, win32com

```
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path_excel)
wb.ActiveSheet
ws = wb.Worksheets('Issue')
print(ws.Comments.Count)
for c in ws.Comments:
    print(c.Parent.Address)
    print(c.Text)
```

I'm not displaying the content, but only the <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.Comment binding method following <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.Comment instance at 0x1716723097048 >>. How can I display the text of the comment. Output here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic8DO.png

Comment: • Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.